# adding frame=none to lstlisting options in \lstdefinestyle gives error with tabular

Tags: tables, listings, matlab-prettifier

`lstlisting` has an option called `frame=`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when I use the `frame=none` in `\lstdefinestyle` and put the `lstlisting` command inside `tabular` or `longtable` I get an error

```
  Forbidden control sequence
```

It seems like a key=value clash of some sort. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab}{style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true,frame=none}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} }
\begin{lstlisting}[style=matlab]
clear all;
the_zeros = [-1 -2];
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Compile

```
pdflatex foo2.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo2.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/matlab-prettifier/matlab-prettifi
er.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg)))
(./foo2.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Runaway definition?
#1\\none\@endpbox \hskip \tabcolsep 
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \lst@temp.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.14 \begin{lstlisting}[style=matlab]

?
```

When I remove the `frame=none` from options, Latex is happy and no error. This option is valid. If I remove the code from inside the tabular, it also compiles ok with the option there:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab}{style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true,frame=none}

\begin{document}        
\begin{lstlisting}[style=matlab]
clear all;
the_zeros = [-1 -2];
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

no error.

question is: Why one gets an error when using `frame=none` inside tabular and longtable but not outside? I need to use the option `frame` and also put the listing inside a table.

I also found that it works if I use `lstset`, like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true,frame=none}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} }
    \begin{lstlisting}
    clear all;
    the_zeros = [-1 -2];
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But I need to use `\lstdefinestyle`   to define the styles, since I have other languages I need to use listings for, and I do not want to set one `lstset` globally. That is why I am loading `listings` as well. I have other `\lstdefinestyle` for other languages, which I did not show up. But only the option `frame=` is the one that gives an error.

TL 2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like a bug but as usual with these things, an extra `{}` helps

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab}{style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
frame=none
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} }
{\begin{lstlisting}[style=matlab]
clear all;
the_zeros = [-1 -2];
\end{lstlisting}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

The bug in listings is here

```
\def\lstKV@SwitchCases#1#2#3{%
    \def\lst@temp##1\\#1&##2\\##3##4\@nil{%
        \ifx\@empty##3%
            #3%
        \else
            ##2%
        \fi
    }%
    \lst@temp\\#2\\#1&\\\@empty\@nil}
```

using `&` as an "arbitrary separator token" is a brave choice, any token could have been used there, but changing it would require changes in several places within the package where this is used.

You could report it to the package maintainer.