# Recent issues with lstlinebgrd package with listings after the latter's update[September 02,2018]

Tags: listings

I could run the program without any problem while highlighting few lines of code using `listings` and `lstlinebgrd` packages. But the recent update of `listings` package v1.7 is giving me error even on the earlier working programs. [For example, this program here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371424/18678). I am giving a similar program, but this time, in beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor,listings, lstlinebgrd}

%   \makeatletter
%   \let\old@lstKV@SwitchCases\lstKV@SwitchCases
%   \def\lstKV@SwitchCases#1#2#3{}
%   \makeatother
%   \usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
%   \makeatletter
%   \let\lstKV@SwitchCases\old@lstKV@SwitchCases
%   
%   \lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
%       \def\lst@PlaceNumber{\lst@linebgrd}%
%       \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
%       {none:\\%
%        left:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
%                   \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}\lst@linebgrd}\\%
%        right:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
%                   \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
%                   \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}\lst@linebgrd}%
%       }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
%   \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Problem}
Test programme:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, gobble=6, linebackgroundcolor={%
    \btLstHL<1>{1,3,5-6}%
    \btLstHL<2>{4}%
}]
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {%
    printf("Hello World!");  
        return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Both give same error as

```
! Package Listings Error: Numbers none unknown.

See the Listings package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.36 ...Error{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
```

Is there any work around? May be the `lstlinebgrd package` author can give me some work around in case if there is no solution at the moment. I am sorry for reporting/posting issues with recent updates.

Comment: A real MWE would be `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}`. `listings` recently changed some internals, maybe `lstlinebgrd` relied on them and broke.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. `lstlinebgrd` was created from this post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18969/18678). lstlisting works fine without `lstlinebgrd` package, however, I would like to have few lines of code highlighted which I used to achieve using lstlinebgrd package earlier.

Comment: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2018-September/007278.html shows that `listings` moved from `&` to `:` in `\lstKV@SwitchCases`. This is what `lstlinebgrd` should do as well. Contact the package maintainer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Recently (https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2018-September/007278.html) `listings` switched the internal separator in the macro `\lstKV@SwitchCases` from `&` to `:`. According to the comments in the source that had to happen because of [adding frame=none to lstlisting options in \lstdefinestyle gives error with tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311383/35864).

**You should contact the maintainer of `lstlinebgrd` via the official channels mentioned in the documentation and ask him to update his package.** (*edit*: Reported at https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/lstaddons/issues/2/lstlinebgrd-broken-with-recent-update-of)

In the meantime here is a very crude workaround that fixes the definition of the affected `\lst@Key{numbers}`. This should restore `lstlinebgrd` to its former glory, but it is not very elegant because it essentially ends up copying the definition of `\lst@Key{numbers}` from `lstlinebgrd.sty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\let\old@lstKV@SwitchCases\lstKV@SwitchCases
\def\lstKV@SwitchCases#1#2#3{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\makeatletter
\let\lstKV@SwitchCases\old@lstKV@SwitchCases

\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \def\lst@PlaceNumber{\lst@linebgrd}%
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none:\\%
     left:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}\lst@linebgrd}\\%
     right:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}\lst@linebgrd}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[linebackgroundcolor={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\color{lightgray}\fi}]
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. I knew zebra works without `lstlinebgrd` package. However, I am trying to highlight few specific lines of code elsewhere instead of the entire code. It was working earlier before that commit you've highlighted though.

Comment: @Khaaba Well, the code here should actually *fix* the `lstlinebgrd` issue. So whatever worked before with `lstlinebgrd` should work with the fix. `linebackgroundcolor` specifically needs `lstlinebgrd` and so I thought that sufficient to show that my code indeed fixes `lstlinebgrd`. If that does not work for you, please add a MWE to your question. (In fact I just checked that my fix also works with the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371424/35864).

Comment: Sorry I could not give you an example sooner. However, both (one reference in the question itself in article class and my MWE in beamer) give the same error whether I supress your macro.

Comment: @Khaaba Do not load `lstlinebgrd` (in `\usepackage{xcolor,listings, lstlinebgrd}`) before you apply the fix. If you do that you already get an error. Load `\usepackage{xcolor,listings}` and then apply the fix, it will load `lstlinebgrd` for you. I can't show you that the code in your question does work, because on my machine the command `\btLstHL` is unknown. But that is unrelated to `lstlinebgrd`.

Comment: @Khaaba OK. I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30877/35864. If I compile https://gist.github.com/moewew/f6f9e42275b18ba7c0c1680ced001603 it works brilliantly for me.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I was thinking yesterday in a similar line!

Comment: I forgot to add earlier. The key/option, backgroundcolor, of original lstlisting fails again. Any work around for this too?

Comment: @Khaaba Contact the author and if you need a workaround ask a new question

Comment: I have put up a new question for workaround at [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476466/18678)

Comment: This is now affecting me under Cygwin. The answer from @moewe works: edit `C:\cygwin64\usr\share\texmf-dist\tex\latex\lstaddons\lstlinebgrd.sty` by changing the three ampersands (`&`) to colons (`:`). I found them after `none`, `left` and `right`.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this upstream, but I’m not sure Martin Scharrer is still around. [His Bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/) is empty now.

Comment: They broke this as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51825/position-tikz-pictures-at-left-margin-of-a-listing-code-block (identical issue)

Comment: Why does `locate lstlinebgrd.sty` not work for me on Debian? (I found it anyway, at `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lstaddons/lstlinebgrd.sty`.)

Comment: @user4417 Not sure about the exact behaviour of `locate`, but for system files that have to do with TeX I usually use `kpsewhich` to find their location. That is the library that is used internally by most TeX tools, so you can usually be sure that the file that is found is the actual file used by TeX and friends.