# Recent issues with lstlinebgrd package with listings after the latter's update [extension]

Tags: beamer, color, listings

This question is in continuation of the earlier [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451532/18678) in which it has been modified to include background color along with `linebackground` color in few lines of code. MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings, pgffor}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %
  % \btIfInRange{number}{range list}{TRUE}{FALSE}
  %
  % Test if int number <number> is element of a (comma separated) list of ranges
  % (such as: {1,3-5,7,10-12,14}) and processes <TRUE> or <FALSE> respectively

\newcount\bt@rangea
\newcount\bt@rangeb

\newcommand\btIfInRange[2]{%
    \global\let\bt@inrange\@secondoftwo%
    \edef\bt@rangelist{#2}%
    \foreach \range in \bt@rangelist {%
        \afterassignment\bt@getrangeb%
        \bt@rangea=0\range\relax%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{ ( #1 >= \bt@rangea) && (#1 <= \bt@rangeb) }%
        \ifnum\result=1\relax%
            \breakforeach%
            \global\let\bt@inrange\@firstoftwo%
        \fi%
    }%
    \bt@inrange%
}%
\newcommand\bt@getrangeb{%
    \@ifnextchar\relax%
        {\bt@rangeb=\bt@rangea}%
        {\@getrangeb}%
}%
\def\@getrangeb-#1\relax{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \bt@rangeb=100000%   \maxdimen is too large for pgfmath
    \else%
        \bt@rangeb=#1\relax%
    \fi%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %
  % \btLstHL<overlay spec>{range list}
  %
\newcommand<>{\btLstHL}[1]{%
    \only#2{\btIfInRange{\value{lstnumber}}{#1}{\color{blue!30}}{}}%
}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %
  % \btInputEmph<overlay spec>[listing options]{range list}{file name}
  %
\newcommand<>{\btLstInputEmph}[3][\empty]{%                                                    
    \only#4{%
        \lstset{linebackgroundcolor=\btLstHL{#2}}%
        \lstinputlisting{#3}%
    }% \only
}%
\makeatletter
    \let\old@lstKV@SwitchCases\lstKV@SwitchCases
    \def\lstKV@SwitchCases#1#2#3{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\makeatletter
    \let\lstKV@SwitchCases\old@lstKV@SwitchCases
    \lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \def\lst@PlaceNumber{\lst@linebgrd}%
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
        {none:\\%
        left:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
            \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep} \lst@linebgrd}\\%
        right:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
            \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
            \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}\lst@linebgrd}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Problem}
Test programme:
\begin{lstlisting}[%
    language=C, 
    gobble=4, 
%   linebackgroundcolor={%
%       \btLstHL<1>{1,3,5-6}%
%       \btLstHL<2>{4}%
%   },
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10}
]
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {%
    printf("Hello World!");  
        return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This MWE [except backgroundcolor key] was provided by [@moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe). Now when I use both keys: `linebackgroundcolor` and `backgroundcolor`, color option of `backgroundcolor` stops working. I tried contacting the author of the package but not succeeded. Any suggestion for work around please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background colour works fine in principle, the problem is that highlighting macro you use fill not only lines to highlight, it fill all other lines with white and thus covers up the gray background.

As a workaround, you can adjust the `\btLstHL` as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings, pgffor}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %
  % \btIfInRange{number}{range list}{TRUE}{FALSE}
  %
  % Test if int number <number> is element of a (comma separated) list of ranges
  % (such as: {1,3-5,7,10-12,14}) and processes <TRUE> or <FALSE> respectively

\newcount\bt@rangea
\newcount\bt@rangeb

\newcommand\btIfInRange[2]{%
    \global\let\bt@inrange\@secondoftwo%
    \edef\bt@rangelist{#2}%
    \foreach \range in \bt@rangelist {%
        \afterassignment\bt@getrangeb%
        \bt@rangea=0\range\relax%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{ ( #1 >= \bt@rangea) && (#1 <= \bt@rangeb) }%
        \ifnum\result=1\relax%
            \breakforeach%
            \global\let\bt@inrange\@firstoftwo%
        \fi%
    }%
    \bt@inrange%
}%
\newcommand\bt@getrangeb{%
    \@ifnextchar\relax%
        {\bt@rangeb=\bt@rangea}%
        {\@getrangeb}%
}%
\def\@getrangeb-#1\relax{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \bt@rangeb=100000%   \maxdimen is too large for pgfmath
    \else%
        \bt@rangeb=#1\relax%
    \fi%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %
  % \btLstHL<overlay spec>{range list}
  %
\newcommand<>{\btLstHL}[1]{%
    \only#2{\btIfInRange{\value{lstnumber}}{#1}{\color{blue!30}}{\color{gray!20}}}%
}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %
  % \btInputEmph<overlay spec>[listing options]{range list}{file name}
  %
\newcommand<>{\btLstInputEmph}[3][\empty]{%                                                    
    \only#4{%
        \lstset{linebackgroundcolor=\btLstHL{#2}}%
        \lstinputlisting{#3}%
    }% \only
}%
\makeatletter
    \let\old@lstKV@SwitchCases\lstKV@SwitchCases
    \def\lstKV@SwitchCases#1#2#3{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\makeatletter
    \let\lstKV@SwitchCases\old@lstKV@SwitchCases
    \lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \def\lst@PlaceNumber{\lst@linebgrd}%
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
        {none:\\%
        left:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
            \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep} \lst@linebgrd}\\%
        right:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
            \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
            \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}\lst@linebgrd}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Problem}
Test programme:
\begin{lstlisting}[%
    language=C, 
    gobble=4, 
   linebackgroundcolor={%
       \btLstHL<1>{1,3,5-6}%
       \btLstHL<2>{4}%
   },
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!20}
]
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {%
    printf("Hello World!");  
        return 0;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this solution stops working with the recent update again :-(

Comment: Sorry, my bad! It STILL works in Beamer but the same doesn't work on book class. The error message says [log is long and I don't how to share] Missing control sequence inserted. <inserted text> \inaccessible l.190 \newcommand<> {\btLstHL}[1]{%