# How to get zebra effect in ‘listings’? (‘listlinebgrd’ seems broken with recent ‘listings’ update)

Tags: listings

I have just install TeXlive 2020 **listings** have been changed and so **lstlinebgrd** seem not work. How can we get back the beautiful zebra effect?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\lstset{%
    language=LaTeX[TeX],%
    basisstyle=\ttfamily,%
    linebackgroundcolor={%
        \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
            \color{green}%
        \else%
            \color{yellow}%
        \fi}
}
\begin{document}
How can we get the zebra effect?
\begin{lstlisting}
$ \cos^{2}\alpha+\sin^{2}\alpha=1 $\\
$ a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2} $\\
$ E=mc^{2} $
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question: [Recent issues with lstlinebgrd package with listings after the latter's update September 02,2018](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451532/134144)  and the corresponding issue at bitbucket: [lstlinebgrd broken with recent update of listings](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/lstaddons/issues/2/lstlinebgrd-broken-with-recent-update-of)

Comment: Thank for pointing out to the right place!