Renaming package on the fly to avoid its detection by \@ifpackageloaded{}?
I am told to use a rather old .sty file (freely available dgruyter.sty from 2017), which does something to lstmisc, a part of the listings package, which breaks on an up to date TeX Live installation.
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{lstmisc}
  [ breaks things...]

Is it possible to still use listings, but avoid the conditional execution of
the offending part of the .sty file?

PS. It might be a symptom of a broken fonts setting by .sty, though, but that's another problem.
Here is a minimal reproducer
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

foo
\end{document}

Running it outputs
...
! Package Listings Error: Numbers none unknown.

See the Listings package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \begin{document}
                    
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \begin{document}
                    
No pages of output.

Running with
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023 Gentoo Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.5

(or other processors in TeX Live 2023).
The style file is somewhere in on the journal website, I forgot where exactly. Or here:
https://gitlab-ext.iosb.fraunhofer.de/hugron/ki-handbuch/-/blob/master/dgruyter.sty

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I'm sorry, I don't understand this comment. I am asking about a (La)TeX programming trick which might be known, not how to compile a particular piece.

You have a template you can't compile. You want to compile said template. There might be better ways than "programming tricks".

Over the past 30 years I published about 80 papers, lots of lecture notes, exam papers, etc. written in LaTeX. I know a thing or two about tools I use. :-)

the style is broken in various places. E.g. it still does \p@=1bp\relax which breaks latex arithmetic. So complain to who ever told you to use it and let them solve the problem. Or make a copy under another name and simply remove the broken code. That is not worth the time for programming tricks.

LaTeX-wise, I've never been so stuck with a journal submission as now. They have a 7+ years old style file with fonts, etc, requiring TeX from 2014.
They also have a newer style file, which they give to book authors (but it's not public). And recently they released a package of fonts, not in this package either.

@UlrikeFischer - thanks, it's very helpful. I thought I might be really missing something.

You don't have to rename anything, you can instead use the same workaround as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451538/36296
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter}

\makeatletter
\let\old@lstKV@SwitchCases\lstKV@SwitchCases
\def\lstKV@SwitchCases#1#2#3{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\lstKV@SwitchCases\old@lstKV@SwitchCases
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none:\\%
     left:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{value `#1' for keyword `numbers' not supported}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
test
\end{lstlisting}

foo
\end{document}


Thanks. Strangely enough, this works with latex and xelatex, but not with lualatex. But that's probably just another bug in .sty file.

@DimaPasechnik The class not working with lualatex has absolutely nothing to do with this problem.

sure, I understand, I not complaining at all about your solution
