# Error with listing and tabular

Tags: tables, listings, tabularx

Here is the code

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    frame=single,
}

\begin{figure*}[tbp!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \lstset{style=mystyle}
            \lstinputlisting[]{code/method.cs}
        \end{tabular}       
    \end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

what's defined in method.cs:

```
public string[] reverse(string[] array)
{
    string[] newArray = new string[array.Length];
    for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
        newArray[array.Length-index-1] = array[index];

    return newArray;
}
```

Error message:

```
Missing { inserted. \lstset{style=mystyle}
Missing } inserted. \lstset{style=mystyle}
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \lstset{style=mystyle}
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode. \lstset{style=mystyle}
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode. \lstset{style=mystyle}
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode. \lstset{style=mystyle}
....
```

It seems removing the tabular environment works but I need that for centering purposes. What's the error?

Edit:

complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    % backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    frame=single,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[tbp!]
    \begin{center}
        %\begin{tabular}{c}
            \lstset{style=mystyle}
            \lstinputlisting[]{method.cs}
        %\end{tabular}      
    \end{center}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Again, I want the `tabular` environment. In any case, I'd like to know why this does not work. So please don't suggest to delete the `tabular` which I already knew would work.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need the tabular environment for centering purposes"? What is wrong with the `center` environment, or instead a simple `\centering` in the figure?

Comment: Also, can you please post a complete MWE? Just adding `\usepackage{listings}` and using class `article` doesn't work at my side at all.

Comment: @TobiBS because neither what you said works.

Comment: Please read my texts again, I didn't propose solutions, I am trying to get an idea of your problem. For this it would be helpful to get a MWE, please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @TobiBS I am answering your question "What is wrong with the center environment, or instead a simple \centering in the figure?" You asked that right?

Comment: @TobiBS Are you telling me you don't even know what you are asking yourself. B.T.W, keep downvoting the question, I am so frustrated man!

Comment: I assume you refer to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5822/134144)   when using `\begin{tabular}{c}` in order to horizontally center a listing.

Comment: On my system, I can't reproduce the error messages you included in your question. For me, the box is already centered on the page even without `figure*`, `center` and `tabular`, although it is a bit wider than the actual textwidth itself. (You can add `\usepackage{showframe}` to your preamble to get a visual representation of the width of the textwidth)

Comment: @leandriis I now understand the need for tabular. I updated my answer accordingly. The frame definition of lstlistings makes use of `&` character and that confuses the tabular environment. So much that even if you use `frame=none` you'd end up with errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your MWE the listings environment is already centered, the problem is that its width is too long and therefore it looks like the text is on the left. A solution for this is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5822/134144) (as @leandriis pointed out).

The thing that causes the error in your case is the frame. You cannot have a frame in a tabular environment. [This is because the definition of frame does not play nice with tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311383/adding-frame-none-to-lstlisting-options-in-lstdefinestyle-gives-error-with-tabu). You should use the tables separators with `\begin{tabular}{|c|}` and `\hline` to create a frame.

MWE of both options with the boundaries shown with geometry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    %backgroundcolor=\color{green},   
    frame=single,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[tbp!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|}
            \hline
            \lstinputlisting[]{method.cs}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}      
    \end{center}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[tbp!]
    \begin{center}
        %\begin{tabular}{|c|}
            \lstset{style=mystyle}
            \lstinputlisting[]{method.cs}
        %\end{tabular}      
    \end{center}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```